# Take an array and transform its values to have a new minimum and maximum

Tags: arrays, matlab, interpolation

I have an array of data in a column with length `354717`. The values vary between `12.8` (min.) and `64.2` (max.).

I want to create an array of the same size with values of `min.= 2.7` and `max.= 27`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to re-scale values to be between 2.7 and 27?

Answer (score 2):

You can first normalize the data so that the dynamic range falls between `[0,1]`.  Once you do this, you can multiply your values by `27 - 2.7 = 24.3`, then offset this by `2.7` to get your values between `[2.7, 27]`.  In other words, if your array is called `A`, do this:

```
normA = (A - min(A)) / (max(A) - min(A)); %// Normalize to [0,1].
out = 24.3*normA + 2.7; %// Change to [2.7, 27]
```

In general, if you want to get your data to be within a certain range, first normalize your data like in the first line of code, then do this:

```
out = (maxD - minD)*normA + minD;
```

Remember, `normA` is the normalized data so that it falls between `[0,1]`.  `minD` and `maxD` are the minimum and maximum values of the desired range you want.  For your case, `minD = 2.7` and `maxD = 27`.

Good luck!